# XMLStreamException: XML version "1.1" is not supported, only XML 1.0 is supported

Tags: java, xml, xslt

about the XML schema versions and the parsing libraries in java, i understand that the best approach is to use "1.0" instead of "1.1" since not all libraries and environments support it and the benefits are little to none, but facing a situation that XML schema "1.1" "must" be supported, i have the following issue:

In this portion of code:

```
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLEventReader reader = factory.createXMLEventReader(XsltTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/an-xsl-file.xsl"));

    String encoding = null;
    if(reader.hasNext()){
        XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
        if(event instanceof StartDocument){
            encoding = ((StartDocument)event).getCharacterEncodingScheme();
        }
    }
```

where "an-xsl-file.xsl" is an XSLT file using XML Schema version "1.1", an XMLStreamException is rasied in when calling reader.nextEvent(), arguing that only XML 1.0 is supported, if i use the same portion of code in an isolated java project (jdk 1.7) with this an nothing else, the snippet works without problem, but when this snippet is run within a particular application with the same JVM it fails the way i mention; this points me to think that there might be dependency issues but i haven't been able to figure out what could it be.

The application is using xml and xslt processing libraries like:

- Saxon 9
- Xerces
- Castor XML
- Xalan

Among others, i'm just starting to get familiar with them so i'm not really sure if there could be a conflict within them, are there any known conflict issues with this? or it is just another different thing? am i missing something? could you please share what you know about it?

btw, for now, i just can't use XML version 1.0 mainly because the document is using characters codes only supported in 1.1.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Ok thanks for the comments, i know this could be a very broad question, but to be honest this is the situation i'm facing right now that's why i'm looking for a hint on what could be the problem hence further investigate and improve the information.

This is part of the exception trace:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,20]
Message: XML version "1.1" is not supported, only XML 1.0 is supported.
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl.next(XMLReaderImpl.java:508)
        at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:62)
        at com.pkg.tofailing.artifact.ClassWithError.getXMLEncoding(ClassWithError.java:216)
```

Where "getXMLEncoding" is the method containing the provided snippet of code, sorry but i might get in trouble if i share more than that, the rest of the stacktrace just contains application classes.

Also, about the xsl file i mention, this is how it starts:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

The failure occurs just reading the first line, where encounters the 1.1 version of XML, if i change it for 1.0 then another error raises in a posterior line with this content:

```
<xsl:text>&#12;&#10;</xsl:text>
```

The character "&#12;" which is unused according to [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html) is the one making it fail on XML 1.0, however for some reason it has to bee supported and XML 1.1 does it, now the problem is with the XML version.

Hope the context be clearer now.

Thanks again!

Comment: Saxon supports [XSD 1.1 for a while now](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/#!conformance/schema11). It also supports XML 1.1. Your text is not very clear to whether your error relates to the used XML version (1.1 is _very, very rare_) or XSD version (which is more common to be 1.1), It would be helpful to show the _exact_ error you get and preferably with the exact tool from the list of tools that is raising it.

Comment: Adding to @Abel's point:  The 1.1 in the XML and XSD versions are completely different.   You should state specific reasons why you need either one or both, and ask a specific question concerning a specific version of a specific library.   Your post wanders across a huge swath of standards and tools without really asking an answerable question.

Comment: @kjhughes, but that may be because the OP says _"i'm just starting to get familiar with them"_..., it can be hard to discern between all these layers of tools and technologies if you first start out (that is not to say that we don't need to get better details).

Comment: At least post a stack trace so that we can see which code causes the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to `com.sun.xml.stream` suggests you have a (possibly old) version of Sun's sjsxp StAX implementation on your classpath. If there is a StAX implementation on the classpath (sjsxp, woodstox, etc.) then that will be used in preference to the built in implementation in the JRE when you do `XMLInputFactory.newInstance()`.

In order to be certain it will work regardless of what else gets added to the classpath, you should depend on a known-good StAX implementation such as Woodstox and create an instance of that directly, rather than rely on the reflection approach of `newInstance()`

```
XMLInputFactory factory = new WstxInputFactory();
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, your approach is good and it should be like that, sadly in my case, there is an already implemented application with tons of components and libraries references including that one, in fact, i just proved that the case was of dependency resolution but is not a final solution because i might be breaking something else, for now i need to be sure i can change or remove that library or with that jar in the classpath, force to use the JRE implementation which i don't now if is possible or introduce for example your suggestion of Woodstox.

Comment: I want to give you the right answer because despite still having some issues, this approach shows a clear working scenario and connects with the main problem. Thanks Sr.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i managed to solve my situation and now it's time to share what i found:

Since i imagined this could be a problem with dependencies at runtime, i did some look up in how to notice where the implementing classes are loaded and at the end i just added the **-verbose:class** VM arg within the execution of the main program to see from where com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl was being loaded and i found that it was being loaded from **sjsxp.jar** which was being loaded at application runtime, i just removed this jar from the classpath and now the function works properly.

The conclusion is that indeed, this was a problem of a dependency resolution at runtime by this jar being used instead of the implementations of the JRE, and that sjsxp.jar which also points to be JSR-173 does not support XML 1.1.

About the -verbose:class VM arg: https://dzone.com/articles/how-use-verbose-options-java 
About he sjsxp.jar (JSR-173): https://sjsxp.java.net/