# How to convert liquibase XML into CSV using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Following is the XML generated:

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
                  <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd"> 
                        <Tester author="Name" id="16384543">
                          <insert tableName="sampletable">
                            <column name="id" valueNumeric="2"/>
                            <column name="name" value="kathy"/>
                            <column name="active" valueBoolean="true"/>
                            <column name="age" valueNumeric="2"/>
                          </insert>
                          <insert tableName="sampletable">
                            <column name="id" valueNumeric="23"/>
                            <column name="name" value="Queen"/>
                            <column name="active" valueBoolean="true"/>
                            <column name="age" valueNumeric="29"/>
                          </insert>
                          <insert tableName="sampletable">
                            <column name="id" valueNumeric="25"/>
                            <column name="name" value="varshan"/>
                            <column name="active" valueBoolean="false"/>
                            <column name="age" valueNumeric="5"/>
                          </insert>
                        </Tester>
                        </databaseChangeLog>
```

I need to convert the XML into CSV like below:
id,name,active,age
2,kathy,TRUE,2
23,Queen,TRUE,29
25,varshan,FALSE,5

**Requirement:** These column attributes will be dynamic and they will be different for different XMLs. Can someone help?

Comment: *"Can someone help?"* Help with what?

Comment: Need to generate CSV file as mentioned ...

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: this is sample XSLT used :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the answer I provided here : [How to convert XML into CSV using XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70215320)

You need to take into account the namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:dbc="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Header -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dbc:databaseChangeLog/dbc:Tester/dbc:insert[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="header">true</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <!-- Data -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dbc:databaseChangeLog/dbc:Tester/dbc:insert"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="dbc:insert">
    <xsl:param name="header"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="dbc:column">
      <!-- For the header take the name attribute, else take the attribute starting with value -->
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$header='true'">
          <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="@*[starts-with(name(),'value')]"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <!-- Insert comma between values, except for last value insert new line -->
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aB9NK5

Comment: What's the jar used for transforming??@sebastien

Comment: @kathir43 what do you mean?

Comment: I mean the XSL engine used for this tranformation

Comment: @kathir43, the online fiddle allows the use of various XSLT processors, the linked example of Sebastien uses XslCompiledTransform, which is Microsoft's XSLT 1 processor for .NET 2.0 and later.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen for clarifying.. I am using eclipse for the transformation and i am not able to perform this conversion as that online fiddle.. can you help me with the setup in Eclipse?

Comment: @kathir43 you stated in your previous question that you were using Xalan, which I believe is XSLT 1.0 compliant, so the transformation I posted should work. When you say you can't perform the transformation, what's not working? Post the error message.

Comment: It gives a blank value after Transformation in eclipse.. It doesn't give any error

Comment: @kathir43, do you get any visible for result for any XSLT stylesheet using `xsl:output method="text"` in your tool Eclipse? Perhaps first try to investigate how to configure Eclipse and XSLT to use that output method.

Comment: Other common reasons for getting a blank output are of course mostly changes in the namespace, the posted answer uses `xmlns:dbc="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"`, any change in the namespace the input URI uses would make that code give a blank result. But that is for you to check in your adaption or use of the answer or the real input you have.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastien

Comment: @kathir43 how did you solve your problem, you stated that you had no output?